# Streaming large Files using Web Api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I got a little question: I would like to stream an large array from my web API to my client. But I got a `System.OutOfMemory` Exception or an `AggregateException`.

My Api looks like this:

```
public List<MyLittlePony> Get()
    { return GetLittlePonys();}
```

And my Client looks like:

```
public string GetRequest(string URL)
{

    using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
    {
        // HTTP POST
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var response = client.GetAsync("").Result;
        string res = "";
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
            // ... Read the string.
            Task<string> result = content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return result.Result;
        }
    }
```

If I'm dealing with a small size of `Objects`, everything works fine. 
But the large one does not work.

I don't want to work with creating files or things like this.

I solved it by using this (Web API):

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{            
    var result = GetLittlePonys();
    var response = Request.CreateResponse();

    response.Content = 
        new PushStreamContent((stream, content, context) =>
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, result);
                stream.Flush();
            }
        });

    return response;
}
```

But now I have the Problem that it takes over 1 minute to transfer about 60000 elements. And this is too long for my client. Can Someone help?

Comment: Is the exception on the server or on the client? Please expand the code to be sufficient to show all the working parts (eg. what is `GetLittlePonys()`?)

Comment: how large is large? why wouldnt you be reading it as a string

Comment: If I'm serializing on the server i get the outofmemoryexception on the server. If not, I got the aggregateException on the Client.

Comment: Large means about 60000 Objects. That GetLittlePonys() just loads the Object from the Database. 
Reading it as a string means outofmemory

Comment: You need to chunk, page, or stream those 60k objects